# Masking with rasterio in Python

Tags: python, rasterio, masking

### Introduction

I have a shapefile for my area of interest (which in this case is Tehran) and also a TIF file that contains the categorical information(cloud status). In this case, I want to mask the TIF file and clip my area of interest (Tehran) using the shapefile provided.

This TIF file just contains numbers between 0 and 5. Therefor if I run the below code:

```py
with rasterio.open("SVDNB_npp_d20120301.vcld.tif") as src:
  print(src.read(1))
```

I will have an output like:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
 [4 4 4 ... 4 4 4]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I am using the below code to **mask** the TIF file(The few first lines are just to change coordinate references system) using the shapefiles provided:

```py
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
from rasterio.windows import Window
from pyproj import Transformer
import geopandas as gpd

# To Change the CRS
df = gpd.read_file('tehran.shp').to_crs(4326)
df.to_file("tehran.shp")

# To mask the data
with fiona.open("tehran.shp", "r") as shapefile:
  shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
with rasterio.open("SVDNB_npp_d20120301.vcld.tif") as src:
  out_image, transformed = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True, filled=True)
  out_meta = src.meta
```

### Issue

The problem is that the masked variable, which in this case is represented by `out_image` variable, is supposed to contain just numbers between 0 to 5 but, unfortunately, whenever I call this variable name, it outputs is like:

```
array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

I am confused and not sure why the numbers now are changed to color-bits.

Comment: Does the TIFF file you're using have any georeferencing data in it? If it does, have you made sure it matches the CRS you're using for `tehran.shp` (epsg:4326)?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: @FelipeD., Yes. As you can see, after reading the shapefile into a Geopandas dataframe, I am using `to_crs(4326)` to match the coordinate references systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works fine. If you look at SVDNB_npp_d20120301.vcld.tif (`src.meta`) you'll see nodata = 255 and you specified `filled=True` which means fill out_image with nodata values.  So when you print your array, you are seeing the nodata values around the masked area of actual values.

If you write out the image and load it in a GIS, you'll see:

```
# To mask the data
with fiona.open("tehran.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("SVDNB_npp_d20120301.vcld.tif") as src:
    out_image, transformed = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True, filled=True)
    out_profile = src.profile.copy()

out_profile.update({'width': out_image.shape[2],'height': out_image.shape[1], 'transform': transformed})
with rasterio.open("tehran.tif", 'w', **out_profile) as dst:
    dst.write(out_image)
```

[image]

If you just want a 1D array of 0-5, just filter out the nodata

```
out_image[out_image<=5]]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. But still, there is a problem for me. I would like to access this array (which contains the number between 0-5) in python itself. How would I be able to get this array from rasterio? Thanks

Comment: `out_image` is a numpy array.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. But still, it contains 255. Do I have to use third-party software like QGIS to get the numbers scaled in the desired format(0-4)?

Comment: There is a way to get the desired scaled numbers. I can re-read the `tehran.tif` file after writing it to a file. this would solve my problem entirely, but, of course, not efficiently. I would appreciate it if you could edit your answer in order to avoid writing and re-reading.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the problem, but I recommend you, cut your raster using gdal.warp

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

#### if you use a geometry:

```
gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, # directory output
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = intputpath, # directoy intput
          cutlineDSName    = shapefile or geojson, # vector file
          cropToCutline    = True, # Select True
          copyMetadata     = True, # optional
          dstNodata        = 0)    # if you have values of zeros
```

#### and if you want to use a extent:

```
gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, 
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = intputpath,
          outputBounds     = (minx, miny, maxx, maxy),
          cropToCutline    = True,
          copyMetadata     = True)
```

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like greetings in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can also arise if the pixel size is larger than the shapefile, resulting in nodata value. simply adding 'all_touched=True' in mask function solves it